# react.js & django, useParams unable to navigate to the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, redirect, react-router-dom

I am current building a react app with django, I am trying to navigate from the HomePage to the DataPage with corrsponding id. However, it return Page not found error. I am using react-router-dom v6.

```
Using the URLconf defined in robot.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
api/
api-auth/
homepage
homepage/data
The current path, homepage/data/54, didn’t match any of these.
```

Here is my App.js

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  renderHomePage() {
    return (
        <HomePage />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path='homepage/' element={this.renderHomePage()} />
          <Route path='homepage/data/:id' element={<DataPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}

const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
render(<App />, appDiv);
```

And I want to navigate to the DataPage below:

```
const EmtpyGrid = theme => ({
    Grid: { ... }
});


function DataPage(props) {
    const { classes } = props;
    const { id } = useParams();

    return (
        <div>
          ... some material ui components ...
        <div/>
    )
};

DataPage.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  };


export default withStyles(EmtpyGrid)(DataPage);
```

I was thinking whether I need configure my url.py in frontend as well, and I need to define a designated value for {id} returned from the materialui component first. Perhaps I need a  `button`  or `<Link><Link/>`  for the navigation instead of just simply typing in the url? Still, no luck after many attempts. I am so confused right now.

If you know what is wrong with my code, please feel free to leave a comment. Thanks

Comment: yes you would want to make use of `<Link>`. What are you using at the moment?

Comment: Currently I am using  ```const navigate = useNavigate()```; in my material-table.  ```onRowClick={(event, rowData) => { navigate('data/')}}```.  I am using the axios to get id from the API, should I destructure the  response.data and map the id into the function like this ```navigate('data/{id}')``` ?

Comment: The app/server also needs to be configured to match where it's deployed to. Typically the server needs to redirect all page requests to sub-routes to the app's `index.html` directory/file so the app loads and allows `react-router-dom` to handle navigating to the appropriate page. Review the [CRA deployment](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) docs to see if they've a section relevant for your server.

Comment: You will have to configure your app server or you can consider using a hash router instead of a Browser router.

https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/HashRouter

Answer (score 1):

After many tries and checking documents, I don't really need to configure my urls.py. I only things that I am missing is to put a parameter in my naviagate() from `onRowClick={((rowData, event) => {navigate('data/');})}` to `onRowClick={((rowData, event) => {let id = event.sample_ID; navigate('data/' + id)})};` I was thinking the problem too complicated.

Thanks you guys for sharing!